# How to store text in flutter app and print the text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, local-storage, flutter-dependencies

Right now I have a document Id that its auto generate for me and I want to store it as text anywhere in the app that I can call to use it as `print docId`

for ex.

```
Future<String> showId() async {
    String retVal = "error";
    try {
      DocumentReference docRef;
      docRef = firestore.collection("Id").add({
         ...
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: docRef.id,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      );
       //Then I want to store docRef.id some where in the app. Because If I don’t store it the 
       //data will be lost. Then I want to use it in the future 
       //too.
      retVal = "success";
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

Is there a way to do that? If you know plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and do like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
prefs.setString(key, value);
```

in you case :

```
Future<String> showId() async {
    String retVal = "error";
    try {
      DocumentReference docRef;
      docRef = firestore.collection("Id").add({
         ...
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: docRef.id,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      );
      
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
      prefs.setString('docRefId', docRef.id);


      retVal = "success";
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

and read it like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
String result = prefs.get(key);
if(result != null){
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: Is there any to store this text string to somewhere else? Like create a class or something. Because If I use sharePreferences it will save to the phone Cache so it can be lost.

Comment: sharePreferences does not save data in cache. It saves data in local storage and just when user delete app it get delete.